# For how long can a will construct of a Green Lantern survive?

Tags: dc, comics, green-lantern, green-lantern-2011

In the *Green Lantern* (2011) movie, Hal Jordan constructed a necklace on the neck of his ex. Could he gift the necklace to her? Can a construct survive indefinitely or only until the death of the creator (if it isn't broken by others)? Or does it survive only until creator's focus on imagination lasts?

I'll allow answers from comics.

Answer (score 3):

In the comics, constructs only remain in existence while the Corpsman's ring is charged.  There's a fun scene from Justice League where the League is building a building (possibly rebuilding their HQ), and having run out of nails, Guy Gardner whips up more with his ring. As his ring runs out of power, the building collapses due to a sudden lack of nails.

Comment: It begs the question: Why did they use such temporary nails in a permanent building?

Comment: Bad writing is my guess

Comment: a) because it was funny b) Guy Gardner was suffering from a slapstick blow to the head, resulting in comedy amnesia, making him a "nice guy", and a little addlepated, and since they preferred the nice version, the JLA chose not to repair him. Hence the poor ring-use choices.